# Change a variable in a loop in Excel each time it runs using a value in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro which loops through the numbers 1 to 17. The problem is, the numbers are no longer 1 to 17 and may change again, so I would like a sheet where those numbers are manually entered in one column, the loop would then act on each cell value in that column.

Basically, I want to replace the "J = 1 To 17" with the contents of a range in a single column.

Here is the original:

```
Sub Nottingham3()
    For j = 1 To 17
        Dim LR As Long, i As Long
        Sheets("Stager").Cells.Clear
        With Sheets("basic list")
            On Error Resume Next
            LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 1 To LR
                If .Range("A" & i).Value = j Then .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Stager").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Next i
        End With
        NottsCopyData
    Next j
End Sub
```

Nothing I've tried is producing exactly what I need.

Comment: Set j to the value of the first cell in your range and then add 1 to it at the bottom of your loop. Loop until j.value = ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this instead of your For/Next loop:

```
Sub Nottingham3()
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long    'Put the dimensioning first
    Range("A1").Select     'Select the first cell of the column.
    Do 
        j=Val(ActiveCell.Value)
        Sheets("Stager").Cells.Clear
        With Sheets("basic list")
            On Error Resume Next
            LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 1 To LR
                If .Range("A" & i).Value = j Then .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Stager").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Next i
        End With
        NottsCopyData
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Activate     'Move one cell down
    Loop until ActiveCell.Value<>""    'Check if cell still has number
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I suspect this is close to where i need to be as i tried activecell previously but couldn't make it work. With your suggestion i get a "compile error: invalid use of property" and it highlights `.Offset`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot to add the `Activate` at the end: `ActiveCell.Offset(1).Activate`

Comment: Yes! This works perfectly, you are nothing short of a Hero! I had to slightly tweak the routine in 'NottsCopyData' but now it does exactly what i need!

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear!

Answer (score 0):

```
j = 1
myCell = Cells(j, 1)

    Do While myCell.Value <> ""
        'actions here

     j = j + 1

Loop
```

Comment: There's a bit more info in the attached post from where I asked the most efficient way to define a starting point for the loop: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429687/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-define-a-starting-cell-for-a-loop/36431511#36431511]

Answer (score 0):

to use a range of "filtering" values you may go like follows

```
Sub Nottingham3()
Dim dataRng As Range, filterRng As Range, cell As Range, found As Range
Dim dataCols As Long

'set your variables once and for all
With Sheets("basic list")
    Set dataRng = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' <== set data range
    dataCols = dataRng.Columns.Count
    Set filterRng = .Range("H3") '<== set the "filter" range first cell only. it'll be extended to its last non empty cell down the column
    Set filterRng = Range(filterRng, .Cells(.Rows.Count, filterRng.Column).End(xlUp)) 'resize filterrng
End With

For Each cell In dataRng
    Sheets("Stager").Cells.Clear 'not sure why clearing target sheet after every loop
    Set found = filterRng.Find(what:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) 'check for the cell value in the filtering range
    If Not found Is Nothing Then cell.Resize(, dataCols).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Stager").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' if found, then copy relevant data only instead of the entire row
    NottsCopyData 'possibly a sub to process data in "Stager"?
Next cell

End Sub
```

but it's also possible to select and copy all relevant data rows in one shot using `AdvancedFilter` method, like follows

```
Sub Nottingham4()

Dim dataRng As Range, filterRng As Range, targetRng As Range

'define the targer range in "Stager" sheet
With Sheets("Stager")
    .Cells.Clear
    Set targetRng = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
End With
If Not IsEmpty(targetRng) Then Set targetRng = targetRng.Offset(1) 'if not the first row then skip one

With Sheets("basic list")
    Set dataRng = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' <== set data range
    Set filterRng = .Range("H3") '<== set the first cell of the "filter" range. it'll be extended to its last non empty cell down the column

    'insert "dummy" headers for exploiting AdvancedFilter() method
    With dataRng
        .Rows(1).Insert
        .Offset(-1).Resize(1).FormulaR1C1 = "=""Head"" & column()"
    End With
    Set dataRng = dataRng.Offset(-1).Resize(dataRng.Rows.Count + 1) 'resize data to include "dummy" headers        
    With filterRng
        .Rows(1).Insert
        .Offset(-1) = "Head" & dataRng.Columns(1).Column 'fill filter range header accordingly
    End With
    Set filterRng = Range(filterRng.Offset(-1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, filterRng.Column).End(xlUp)) 'resize filterrng

    'filter and copy and past to target cell
    dataRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=filterRng, CopyToRange:=targetRng

    'remove the "dummy" headers cells
    dataRng.Rows(1).Delete
    filterRng.Rows(1).Delete
    targetRng.EntireRow.Delete
End With

NottsCopyData 'possibly a sub to process ALL data in "Stager"?

End Sub
```

as you see, there's no looping through cells nor multiple copying and pasting so it's very fast should you have to process a lot of rows

the code's length is mostly for "preparing" needs, since the actual copy&pasting is made by one statement only, which is

```
dataRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=filterRng, CopyToRange:=targetRng
```

of course, this one shot operation may need some revisions in `NottsCopyData` sub (or at least I assume it is a sub) which should be adapted to process data filtered by all conditions, instead of by one condition only

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that you could get the same result without an outer loop if you used a lookup function (the list is in another sheet because you probably don't want to copy the list along with the other stuff):-

```
Sub Nottingham5()
Dim result As Variant
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Sheets("Stager").Cells.Clear
With Sheets("basic list")
LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LR
    result = Application.VLookup(.Range("A" & i).Value, Sheets("lookup").Range("a:a"), 1, False)
    If Not IsError(result) Then .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Stager").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Next i

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Of course the other answers are great - just wanted to practise my (limited) VB skills.